# How to show a number field multiplied by 1000

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field on the screen that looks like this:

```
Limit    1000
```

The values are coming from elsewhere and need to remain that way, however, I want it to show `100,000`

The field is set up like below:

```
<li for="Limit" label="Limit">
  <label>Limit:&nbsp;</label>
  <span class="value">1000</span>
</li>
```

I've tried a few ways to get the value but haven't been successful and I'm not sure how to show the value to the thousandth. I'm new to JS so any help would be greatly appreciated.I've tried getting the value using this

```
var limit = $("[for='Limit']").val()
```

but haven't been successful. The output I am looking for is 100,000 and yes the field values can change which is why i was using the name of the field itself.

Comment: Please don't spam programming language tags.  I do not see any Java or Javascript.  If this is javascript, please show the code in a [mre] and remove the Java tag.

Comment: Please specify a bit more what you mean. Provide several examples of input and expected output, what you've tried so far, and what isn't working.

Comment: Could you edit the question? Also please provide what you want the output to look like, and whether it should vary based on input.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the example there, not in the comment section.

Comment: *`but haven't been able to parse the value nor get it to show 100,000`*  That doesn't tell us how to help you.  You need to show a complete working example, the output you want ,and the output you get.  But just enough to demonstrate and not to inundate us with code or output.

Comment: I updated my comment

Comment: There is no element in your HTML matching `[for='Alias_C_CustomISOCAStateDefault_CombinedSingleLimit']`. If you're intending to target the `li[for="Limit"]`, then that is an `li` and will not have a `value`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post. So there is no way to get the value of that field?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure `<span>` is allowed to be a sibling to `<li>`.

Comment: It has `innerText`, rather than a value. inputs, selects, and textareas have values.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the element you're targeting with the `[for]` attribute is an `li`, which has no `value` property. In addition, the text you're trying to target is in the child `.value` span. You can amend the selector and then use `text()` to retrieve it.

From there, if you're expecting to convert `1000` in to `100,000` then you need to multiply it by `100`, not `1000`. You can achieve that by passing a function to jQuery's `text()` method. This accepts the current value as an argument which you can use in your calculation and then return the result to display in the element.

Note the use of `toLocaleString()` in the below example. This will include the thousands grouping. You can also force a culture setting, if required.

```js
var limit = $("[for='Limit'] .value").text((_, t) => (+t * 100).toLocaleString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li for="Limit" label="Limit">
    <label>Limit:&nbsp;</label>
    <span class="value">1000</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="value">1000</span>
```

Also not the tweak I made to the HTML; `li` must be contained within an `ol` or `ul` element. I'm assuming this is just a mistake made when copying your code in to the question, though.

Comment: yes, Thank you! You are correct, it was a mistake while copying code over.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Also worth noting that `val()` in jQuery is only for user input elements.